# how can i add zeros to all the numbers of the user entered array and convert all numbers to the same digits?

Tags: python

I cannot use any functions like zfill

```
n = int(input('n: '))
arr = [None]*n
for p in range (n):
    arr[p] = int(input())
```

for example if user enters 62,32,654,32649, i want them to convert to 00062,00032,00654,32649

Comment: Please update your question with examples of expected `arr` for sample user inputs. Your example of `00062` is unclear.

Comment: Work with the string instead of int, go through entries to find largest length and prepend "0" to each string until the desired length is reached.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a format string:

```
values = [62,32,654,32649]
print(*(f"{n:05}" for n in values))

00062 00032 00654 32649
```

This applies to printing or manipulating the data as strings.  When you make them `int()` there is no notion of leading zeroes in the internal representation of the numbers.

To pad to the largest number you can use nested format strings:

```
size = max(map(len,map(str,values)))
print(*(f"{n:0{size}}" for n in values))
```

Comment: I think he means that you should pad all the numbers to fit the "biggest" one

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
n = input('n: ')
l = [x.zfill(5) for x in n.split(',')]
z = ','.join(l)
print(z)
```

input:

```
62,32,654,32649
```

output:

```
00062,00032,00654,32649
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the `.format()` method for strings. In the [following page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/) code snippet #8 can be of help. In your case I would suggest

```py
n = int(input('n: '))
arr = [None]*n
for p in range (n):
    arr[p] = "{:05d}".format(int(input()))
```